# Why does RelativeSource Binding behave inconsistent?

Tags: c#, wpf

Note: I know I should use `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` to resolve the presented issue but I want to know *why* the issue appears.

I have a custom control `CustomTextControl` with a `ControlTemplate` where I use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomTextControl}}` and when I display it inside a `Window`, everything is displayed as expected.

But when I try to print the same control with the `PrintVisual` method of `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog`, the binding is not evaluated correctly.

Example:

```
public class CustomTextControl : ContentControl
{
    static CustomTextControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomTextControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomTextControl)));
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml (`local` refers to the `xmlns:local` definition of my project namespace):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomTextControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomTextControl}">
                <TextBlock
                    Background="Red"
                    Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomTextControl}},Path=Content}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

MainWindow content:

```
<Grid>
    <local:CustomTextControl Content="My text to be displayed" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10"/>

    <Button Content="PrintTest" Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,100,10,10"/>
</Grid>
```

The control is displayed with red background and the specified text content.

MainWindow code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    var e = new CustomTextControl();

    e.Content = "My text to be printed";
    e.Margin = new Thickness(30);
    e.UpdateLayout();

    var print = new PrintDialog();

    if (print.ShowDialog() != true) return;

    var w = print.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize.Width ?? 600;
    var h = print.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize.Height ?? 1000;
    e.Measure(new Size(w, h));
    e.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, w, h));

    print.PrintVisual(e, "Test Printing");
}
```

As you see, I create a separate control that's sufficiently similar to the control inside the mainwindow.

Result: the printed document contains the red background but not the text content.

My question: why is the text content displayed in the window but not in the printed document?

## Update

If I place a `MessageBox.Show("Test");` right before the `print.PrintVisual(e, "Test Printing");`, then the printed document has red background, so it is some sort of work/timing issue.

I was able to resolve my specific example by using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` on the printing statement but for a little modified example involving a Data-Bound `CheckBox`, this was not enough, even with `DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens, because your control isn't in visual tree. RelativeSource binding searches in parent of current control. 
You can try to replace your **RelativeSource** with **TemplateBinding** inside Template definition.

Try to Use

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomTextControl}},Path=Content}"/>
```

instead of:

```
Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
```

Comment: But isn't my control basically the root of a visual tree? Also, the same thing happens if I wrap the control in another layer of UI elements to ensure it has a parent. So if the visual tree is the problem, it would be interesting to have some documentation source about elements that qualify as visual tree roots and elements that do not. As mentioned, I know about the `TemplateBinding` and `TemplatedParent` options.

Comment: I've tried to launch your example, but with default button and with default button it works well. So I changed template to use RelativeSource, but instead of using my template, default template was applied. So I've added direct style definition 

     e.Style = (Style)this.Resources["example"];

after this it worked as expected. So my assumptions about FindAncestor were wrong. In your case seems like something wrong with template applying.